# Sending ARP requests with SmokePing

Tags: networking, ping, network-monitoring, arp, icmp

I have been using SmokePing to monitor my local network for some time now and I'm happy with its graphs and email alerts. I use the fping probe and it works as expected.

I found however that, every now and then, some of my hosts won't respond to ARP requests (due to yet-to-be-discovered WiFi issues). ICMP pings would often work in these cases, since the SmokePing machine would use its ARP cache, but I need to make sure that my hosts are ARP-reachable.

Hence my question: how can I make SmokePing send ARP requests instead of ICMP requests? I googled for hours for a solution and I couldn't find any probe that employs ARP.

Comment: Alternatively, I would consider reducing the ARP cache timeout so entries expire quicker.  This could be a simple way to increase the accuracy of the ARP cache.

Comment: The ARP cache is as accurate as it can be (things don't change too much around here). The problem is that when the cache expires, it can't be renewed because some devices won't reply to ARP. That's what I want to monitor with SmokePing.